# Powershell - Pass in and execute string without using WinRM

Tags: powershell

I am trying to utilize a custom PS function that will accept a powershell command as a string parameter and execute/store the results in a variable within the function itself to be referenced later.  After doing some research, I found a way of doing this by passing in "Get-WinEvent" as a string variable to the function and then within the function converting that variable to a scriptblock like so:

`$PowershellQueryScript = [Scriptblock]::Create($PowershellQuery)`

Once I did that, I called the variable in my foreach loop and stored the results like so:

`$myResults = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $PowershellQueryScript`

Now the error I receive is in regards to WinRM not being enabled ("Connecting to remote server myServer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request.") and unfortunately I do not think I will be allowed to make this settings change in production.  If I were to call this command directly from my server -> production without utilizing Invoke-Command then everything works as expected as I think it does not have to create a remote PS session on the remote server so WinRM is not required.

Are there any other workarounds for allowing a user to call my function with a string and have that string be executed in the function itself WITHOUT having to enable WinRM?

Comment: Use DCOM authentication. Powershell remoting defaults to WinRM. Why not enable WinRM?

Comment: Settings changes on prod servers require approval so I'd rather not have to make the change even if it is minor.  Also, I imagine PS remoting is a security risk so it would be scrutinized further. Edit: Looks like it is enabled by default, but not sure why I have issues when running my command if that is the case.  I know RPC calls work, but can't do that AND still utilize my PS function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: You can use DCOM but, it's as you said, it's enabled by default. It's probably the service that isn't started.

Comment: "By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet."   You can test if WinRM is running on local and/or remote computers by running `Test-WSMan`

Comment: I honestly believe the best approach is to get WS-Man enabled in an organisation as long as you review the security docs for it, as you have started to above. It's as much of a risk as any other connection in your environment - you mitigate them by restricting access to a set of endpoints, requiring credentials and having good credential management in place. It is better than the alternative which is people asking for ways to workaround it, doing things that create security risks or using tools like PSExec, etc.

Comment: To compliment Ash's comment, WinRM can be configured over HTTPS as well, instead of default HTTP.

Comment: I can't use DCOM rpc as I want to pass a string dynamically into my function and execute that string, which requires WinRM to be enabled and that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found out WinRM was already enabled and the proper firewall settings were already configured as well.  The problem was that I was using cnames and not FQDNs (Fully Qualified Domain Names) so the DNS was not resolving properly.  Issue is resolved by converting cname to a value that can be resolved:

```
$ServerFQDN = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry([string]$ServerCname).HostName
```